# .cursor() gives MySQL not available

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to connect to an existing MySQL database from Python and creating a table. Following is the code :

```
from getpass import getpass
from mysql.connector import connect, Error

def connect_db():
    try:
        with connect(
                host="localhost",
                user=input("Enter username: "),
                password=getpass("Enter password: "),
                database="online_movie_rating",
            ) as connection :
            return connection
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

create_ratings_table_query = """
CREATE TABLE ratings (
    movie_id INT,
    reviewer_id INT,
    rating DECIMAL(2,1),
    FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(reviewer_id) REFERENCES reviewers(id),
    PRIMARY KEY(movie_id, reviewer_id)
);
"""
cnx = connect_db()

print(cnx)

cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute(create_ratings_table_query)
cnx.commit()
```

When I comment the last 3 lines, I am able to print the connection object. However, when I uncomment and try to run, I get the following error :

```
cursor = cnx.cursor()
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.
```

I am on a Fedora 33 OS, Python 3.8.5 in conda environment and use VS Code as IDE. Have already pip installed the mysql-connector-python.

Can someone please help ? Have done a lot of googling but could not find a clear answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you do `connection.cursor()` inside `connect_db`? Or, you may fail to establish connection from the beginning.

Comment: When return in `connect_db` you will leave the `with` block and that will result in the connection being closed.

Comment: Thank you - this answer and comment helped. I removed the function, moved the connection inside and it worked.

Comment: No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Comment: Fine, I have accepted the answer below, which is essntially the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
def connect_db():
    try:
        with connect(
                host="localhost",
                user=input("Enter username: "),
                password=getpass("Enter password: "),
                database="online_movie_rating",
            ) as connection :
            return connection
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
```

But as soon as your `return connection` executes, the `with connect(...) as connection:` block terminates and the connection is closed. So you would be returning a closed connection if the connect ever succeeded. You need instead:

```
def connect_db():
    try:
        connection = connect(
                host="localhost",
                user=input("Enter username: "),
                password=getpass("Enter password: "),
                database="online_movie_rating",
            )
        return connection
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
```

The connection can be closed explitily with `cnx.close()` by the caller or it will be closed automatically when there are no more references to this connection, for example when `cnx` goes out of scope.

**Also, if there is an error in connecting, function `connect_db` will return `None`. So perhaps the caller should check for this possibility.**

The actual exception you are getting, however, is explained as:

> This exception is raised for errors which are related to MySQL's operations. For example: too many connections; a host name could not be resolved; bad handshake; server is shutting down, communication errors.

You need to check your connection parameters. But clearly you must make the source changes indicated above.